# How to get PUT parameters using HttpFoundation

Tags: php, put, symfony-http-foundation

How can I get *PUT* body parameters using HttpFoundation component (without Symfony)?
According the docs `Request::createFromGlobals` only about POST, GET ... but not PUT. So here I cannot use like `$request->request->all()`, it will be empty.

I believe there is a more nicer way then

```
$request = Request::createFromGlobals;
$content = $request->getContent();
// Parsing $content
```

This way `json_decode($request->getContent(), true);` returns `null`.

Please share your experience.

Comment: Body parameters will be contained in `$_POST`, even if method is `PUT`. There is no `$_PUT` in PHP, only `$_GET` and `$_POST`.

Comment: Yes, so here I'm asking in terms of HttpFoundation.

Comment: What are you asking exactly? Just use `Request::createFromGlobals()` and it'll work fine, there's no black magic going on.

Comment: https://joshtronic.com/2014/06/01/how-to-process-put-requests-with-php/

Comment: `Request::createFromGlobals()request->all()` for POST is ok, I can get params, but on PUT it returns null.

Comment: I found out that it's not related to HttpFoundation. 
When I make POST request `var_dump($_POST)` gives proper params. But when I change to PUT the `$_POST` is empty. I'm using Postman for testing.

Comment: Ok, I think I've solved my problem. Everything is ok when use `x-www-form-urlencoded`.